# Python: Executing windows tracert

Tags: python, windows

I'm new to Python and trying to write my first program.

What I'm trying to do is modifying windows `tracert` command output by putting a date on the output.

```
c:\Python\Codes>more tr.py
import os
import time
print (time.strftime("\nDate: %d %B %Y"))
os.system('tracert')

c:\Python\Codes>tr.py 127.0.0.1

Date: 09 March 2018

Usage: tracert [-d] [-h maximum_hops] [-j host-list] [-w timeout]
               [-R] [-S srcaddr] [-4] [-6] target_name

Options:
    -d                 Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.
    -h maximum_hops    Maximum number of hops to search for target.
    -j host-list       Loose source route along host-list (IPv4-only).
    -w timeout         Wait timeout milliseconds for each reply.
    -R                 Trace round-trip path (IPv6-only).
    -S srcaddr         Source address to use (IPv6-only).
    -4                 Force using IPv4.
    -6                 Force using IPv6.

c:\Python\Codes>
```

However, the `tracert` command in Python code was not executed correctly.

This is what I'm expecting.

```
c:\Python\Codes>tr.py 127.0.0.1

Date: 09 March 2018

Tracing route to 127.0.0.1
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  127.0.0.1

Trace complete.

c:\Python\Codes>
```

Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: I do like that you asked this question by explaining what you're trying to do. Also your actual vs. expected output is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not passed the python shell argument on to `tracert`, and so the Windows `tracert` is advising you to supply an argument (e.g. the "127.0.0.1")

The simplest way is to change your code to do two more things

1. get the shell argument you supplied to the python script.  Python has an array in the `sys` module:  `sys.argv`, which contains the script arguments.
2. pass that to `tracert`.  You can use string catenation with the `+` operator.

Here's a simple change:

```
import os
import time
import sys
print (time.strftime("\nDate: %d %B %Y"))
os.system('tracert' + ' ' + sys.argv[1])
```

Note, I had to add a space between the call to tracert, and the argument. 
 I called it out specially to make you see it, but you could also just call `'tracert '` with the space at the end.

Here it is, running on my Mac (which has `traceroute` instead, but the idea is the same):

```
[mjl@milo:~/hax]
[18:42](hax)$ python tr.py 127.0.0.1

Date: 09 March 2018
traceroute to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.312 ms  0.077 ms  0.043 ms
[mjl@milo:~/hax]
[18:42](hax)$
```

A (slightly) better way is to use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
import time
import sys
print (time.strftime("\nDate: %d %B %Y"))
subprocess.run(["tracert",sys.argv[1]])
```

Now you don't have to mess with adding a space after the command.  But you must supply the command and all its arguments as elements in an array to `subprocess.run()`.

Note:- none of these codes do any error checking. If you run your `tr.py` without an argument it will give an error:

```
[mjl@milo:~/hax]
[18:42](hax)$ python tr.py

Date: 09 March 2018
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tr.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.system('traceroute' + ' ' + sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```